# How to use the 'left-arrow' key to move my cursor when typing into a cell for the first time

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using Excel, there are many instances when I need to move the cursor back 'in-between' characters, like in the case where I write open and closed parenthesis and *then* fill in the rest:

```
()*my_cursor

(*my_cursor)

(stuff)
```

Unfortunately, when I try to do that, Excel assumes I want to go to the cell left of the cell I'm working on. After I click back to the cell I need, I don't get this problem. How do I disable this feature of Excel? It's really bugging me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It will take an extra keypress but F2 will do it:

()<kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>stuff

Will give you

```
(stuff)
```

Comment: This is the best way. Using F2 instead of clicking in the formula bar or double clicking the cell is the most efficient. +1

Comment: I should have probably mentioned this in the question but I'm using a Macbook Pro so F2 didn't work. Luckily it's easy to find the equivalent of F2 on the mac, which is *ctrl+U*.

Comment: Isn't there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: @Greg It just occurred to me that Apple hates F keys XD.. Thanks Paul, great tip! I wish I could permanently reverse the function though, that is to press F2 before arrow to insert a cell reference or move to another cell, but normally the arrows should move the cursor within the current cell.